Python Playwright wait for post response
I'm working on webscraping a website and there's a section where I have to input filtering dates and then, after pressing a 'Go' button like the following, wait for the table on the website to change and display the results:
<input type="button" name="ctl00$CP$HeaderControl$GoButton" value="Go" onclick="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$CP$HeaderControl$GoButton','')" id="ctl00_CP_HeaderControl_GoButton" title="Go" class="goButton">

Is it possible using Playwright Python to wait for some sort of event to indicate that the table is ready with the results, in order to continue with webscraping?

It's possible. wait_for_response, wait_for_function or wait_for_selector are some of the tools you can use. Please share the page and your code so far as a complete, runnable [mcve] so I can help specifically. Thanks.

I cannot find wait_for_response in official docs
